# Opensips or freeswitch

Tags: sip, freeswitch, opensips

I am trying to make sip server.
I Was trying to install Opensips and Freeswitch.
But I have a basic question here,

What to choose Opensips or freeswitch ?

I also found that opensips is integrated with freeswitch. Why we need to integrate opensips with freeswitch?

Any info on this will be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, take a look at:
http://www.opensips.org/Documentation/Tutorials-OpenSIPSFreeSwitchIntegration

It all depends on what you need.

Answer (score 4):

**Opensips is a SIP proxy**
Opensips Handles SIP Signaling and you can customize the routing via opensips scripts. There are also pre-configured scripts available to make routing for different scenarios.

Opensips have many modules to implement features like LCR, CDR, Dialog Handling, Dynamic routing, Fallback Mechanism, Load balancing etc 
Using the module API, one can write customized script for routing SIP messages.

Media will be handled by rtpproxy or rtpengine

http://www.opensips.org/Documentation/Webinars

**Freeswitch is a Softswitch or SoftPBX**

Freeswitch is not just for SIP, It can bridge different VoIP Protocols and telecom Hardwares, Its a PBX system so it can also have features like Call Transfers, CDR, DID Routing, LCR, IVR, Conference etc

It also takes care of Media, Media transcodings

> Its not mandatory to use Opensips with Freeswitch, both serves
>   different purpose. Opensips scales higher as it meant to act only on
>   SIP Signalling compare to Freeswitch. But it depends on requirement
>   whether Opensips is enough to suit your requirement.